# Is it possible to use Hibernate without foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, liferay

One simple question if somebody may had an experience in this topic:

> Is it possible to use Hibernate (with full functionality) without
>   foreign keys at the tables...?

In my case i need to this because i want to `reverse engineering a liferay database` and entities, and in liferay the foreign key just mess ups things (Liferay doesn't support foreign keys), so it would be a good solution if i can just switch off foreign keys alteration of in some hibernate parameter (i know it is not works, so maybe some workaround needed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't care about foreign keys at all. Whether you have one or not doesn't matter. Suppose you have

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;
}
```

then, as long as every value of procuct.category_id actually refers to an existing category.id (or is null), then everything will work fine. Of course, it would be a good idea to actually enforce that by setting a foreign key constraint, but Hibernate doesn't need one.

Comment: Yeah absolutly, thanks mate, this was my first tought, thanks... I I think it is fasten the process a little bit, if we use foreign keys.
And anyway hibernate in his own alter the tables with foreign keys! This is 100% sure, so do you know any paramter which gives to hibernate it will not alter tables with foreign key? Or i need to setup with DBA admin a permisson to not be able to alter...

Comment: foreign keys are great because they make sure your data stay in a coherent state. They don't make anything faster. Actually, they make things slightly slower, since the database has to check that you're not storing incorrect values. Hibernate doesn't alter your schema unless you explicitely tell it to create or update it with the `hbm2ddl.auto` property.

Comment: Ok thanks. I dont know precisly where i've read that it should be faster, but yeah data integrity is also an important issue.  hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is update, so this is the only property i can use, i hoped that here is an explicitly property for foreign key alters...